# Elastic Enterprise Search - Is it a best practice to index data of two different json schema in a single index

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I'm trying out Elastic Enterprise Search with Elasticsearch. I have a couple of questions on data indexing.

When referring to Elasticsearch documentation, I read that there is a limit to the number of fields that an Elasticsearch index could have. Since Elasticsearch is used with Elastic Enterprise Search I believe there is no arguing that the same applies here. In that case lets say I have multiple document types with various fields. For an example Person.json and Dog.json, they both have different properties. So when indexing I use one search engine in Elastic Enterprise Search to index both Person and Dog so that when I query using the Elastic Enterprise Search API I'll get results which are both Person and Dog depending on the search term.

Is this the way to go,or should I specify a seperate search engine for each schema type?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your person.json and dog.json contains different fields as your heading suggest and weather to create a separate index for these entities or have them in a single index, depends on the various use-cases you have in your application and you will not find elasticsearch marking one approach better than other and mainly will explain the pros/cons based on a particular context(like relevance, performance, management etc).

Please refer to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997602/4039431) SO answer, where I talked about various pros/cons of both the approach and [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225081/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-joao-furriel) to get more context why OP chose an approach based on his use-case, after knowing the pros/cons.

Comment: I read the references that you had linked and I would like to know if multiple index is allowed when using Elasticsearch Enterprise Search. Because the dashboard it provides is different from Kibana and when I used GET /_cat/indices API in Elasticsearch it shows all indexes prefixed with a period, where I read that they are indices created by Enterprise Search (same could be noticed when linking with Kibana as well). So do you know if a engine in Enterprise search supports multiple indices?

Comment: @DarthShirr, sorry for the delay in response, I am pretty sure that enterprise search internally uses the elasticsearch as a search engine, and elasticsearch supports the multiple indices, and for scalability and other things(mentioned in my prev answer) IMO they are creating multiple indices, although not sure about the strategy(based on size, time or data-type) are they creating indices, this better if you can confirm on http://discuss.elastic.co/ where their employees might confirm it

Comment: @DarthShirr Also I am not using enterprise search as is not open source, this might be the reason I couldn't find the internal info , and you should also consider this factor(flexibility) before finalizing the solution

Comment: Sure will do, thanks a lot for the directions. I'd see what I could find.

I found below links hope it will help someone who checks this post later on
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-you-connect-elastic-search-ui-to-elasticsearch-instead-of-app-search/254312
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/have-multiple-search-hits-on-one-line/252394